# Delta Query for user resource: How to get only changed attributes

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, change-tracking

I am using Microsoft Graph API delta query to track changes in my Azure AD.

I want to obtain only changed properties. So I have set '**ocp-aad-dq-include-only-changed-properties**' header value to '**true**' to get only changed properties. But even after using this header I am receiving all user properties.

Is there any other option to get only changed properties? or Do I need to use any other header?

Given below the detail description of the operations that I am trying.

Example:

- **Initial Delta request**

  ```
   GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=displayName,givenName,surname
  ```

  Headers:

  ```
   ocp-aad-dq-include-only-changed-properties : true
  ```

  Response:
  In the initial response, I am getting all users.
- **DeltaLink request** after updating 'displayName' attribute

  ```
   GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$deltatoken=KhFiGlAZqewNAThmCVnNxqPu5gOBegrm1CaV
  ```

  Headers:

  ```
   ocp-aad-dq-include-only-changed-properties : true
  ```

  Here I have added 'ocp-aad-dq-include-only-changed-properties' header still I am getting all attributes of the User

  Response:

  ```
  {
      "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
      "@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$deltatoken=o8xFasdpZ7QDP14TyDfj9AeibJxMlXAtgB0Nb",
      "value": [
          {
              "businessPhones": [],
              "displayName": "jhon4",
              "givenName": null,
              "jobTitle": null,
              "mail": null,
              "mobilePhone": null,
              "officeLocation": null,
              "preferredLanguage": null,
              "surname": null,
              "userPrincipalName": "jhon.smith@testdomain.onmicrosoft.com",
              "id": "942h93c9-af17-6sad2d98cc8"
          }
      ]
  }
  ```
- **Update Request**

  ```
   PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/jhon.smith@testdomain.onmicrosoft.com
  ```

  Payload:

  ```
  {
    "displayName": "jhon4",
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The `ocp-aad-dq-include-only-changed-properties` header is a feature of the [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-differential-query#AdditionalDifferentialQueryFeatures) and isn't supported in [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_users).

While they're extremely similar, these two APIs have several distinct features differences (such as this one). You can read more about the differences (and the overall plan) at [Microsoft Graph or the Azure AD Graph](https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph).

Comment: Do you know when Microsoft will add optimization headers for Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an ETA. I would recommend asking for this in the UserVoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis

Answer (score 0):

to get only the changed properties, use this header:
prefer:return=minimal